# Updating a Magento product attribute's database field type after creation

Tags: magento

The scenario: You've created a product attribute programmatically using a database migration.  Several months later you'd like to change that attribute from a `VARCHAR` to a `TEXT` field type.

How do you change the field type of an EAV attribute after creation while preserving the data?

My gut feeling is that this isn't supported directly through Magento's setup classes, due to the myriad of tables that would need to be touched, records that would need to be updated and content that would need to be copied from table to table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not going to pretend this is the prettiest solution around, and I'm doubtful it's database agnostic, but here's my solution:

```
<?php
/** @var $this Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */

$this->startSetup();

$attribute_id = $this->getAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'your_attribute_code',
    'attribute_id'
);;

if (!is_numeric($attribute_id)) {
    Mage::throwException("Couldn't run migration: Unable to find attribute id");
}

/** @var Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql $connection */
$connection = $this->getConnection();

$connection->beginTransaction();

/**
 * Copy the data from the VARCHAR table to the TEXT table.
 */
$connection->query("
        INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_text 
            (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
        SELECT
            entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value
        FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
        WHERE attribute_id = ?
    ",
    array($attribute_id)
);

/**
 * Update eav_attribute to use the text table instead of the varchar.
 */
$connection->query("UPDATE eav_attribute SET backend_type = 'text' WHERE attribute_id = ?", array($attribute_id));

/**
 * Delete the attribute values from the VARCHAR table.
 */
$connection->query("DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = ?", array($attribute_id));
$connection->commit();

$this->endSetup();
```

Comment: For this operation, there's no "pretty way" as it's not built into the EAV resource layer. The only (entirely semantic) change would be to use the `Mage_Eav_Entity_Setup::updateAttribute()` to change the `backend_type`.

Comment: @benmarks Thanks, I'll use `updateAttribute()`. I had it in my mind it wouldn't support that field due to the implications on the rest of the tables.

Comment: I have 20k products, by default all products assigned both websites in multi-store. How can I remove all products from selected one website in multi-store?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I confirm it's not supported.

You could try to update tables with SQL but it will be a pain ...

I would export all your products, apply the upgrade script that modify your attribute backend table and re-import all your products.
That way magento will fill automatically the new table (catalog_product_entity_text) used by your attribute.

After that, you should clean your varchar table to delete unused values linked to your products (values that will be never deleted nor updated as your attribute's product is now TEXT)

Comment: Yes, it is *imperative* to delete the values from `catalog_product_entity_varchar` - otherwise the legacy values from this table will overwrite the values from `catalog_product_entity_text` in the UNION select.